# Using For loop to retrieve multiple rows in Oracle procedure

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, join, plsql, cursor

Im working on stored procedure where I need to retrieve a set of results and process each element individually and then return the entire result.(using 3 different tables)

Im not too familiar with databases, but heres what I was able to come up with..

```
create or replace procedure GET_EMP_RSLT
  IS

CURSOR ecursor IS select emp_id from temp_employee where 'some condition';

BEGIN

FOR empidset in ecursor  

  LOOP

  Select * from 

    (select * from payroll_info where emp_id = empidset.emp_id) a

    left join 

    (select * from benefit_info where emp_id = empidset.emp_id) b 
     on a.emp_id = b.emp_id    

  END LOOP;

END;
```

On execution, I get the following error..

```
an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement : "Select * from"
```

can anyone please explain on how do I correct this error and get the required results?

PS. Im using Oracle 9i & TOAD 9

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 4):

The SELECT inside of your loop needs to have an INTO clause to process the values - it is not clear from your code what you're trying to do, but I suspect the nested SELECT's/JOIN inside of the cursor loop could be better written as a three table join in the main cursor.

Comment: +1, particularly for the recommendation to move all selects into main cursor. Your recommendation that the INTO clause will fix the problem assumes the select inside the loop only returns one row for each iteration over the cursor, else you get an ORA-1422 error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add an INTO clause to specify which local variables to place the selected data, eg.

```
select ID, Name
  into myID, myName
from emp
```

Comment: Assumes the select returns one row.

Answer (score 1):

Below is a possible solution, making a fair number of assumptions.  As written, it returns the result as a ref cursor containing data from all 3 tables (it would be trivial to make it return a ref cursor for each table, but that would be more work for a dubious result).

However, unless you're really doing something in the PL/SQL that you can't do in SQL, you'd be much better off doing this directly in SQL.

```
create object EMP_PAYROLL_BENEFIT as object (
   em_id number,
   some_payroll_column number,
   some_benefit_column number);

create type NT_EMP_PAYROLL_BENEFIT as table of EMP_PAYROLL_BENEFIT;

create or replace procedure GET_EMP_RSLT(p_output OUT sys_refcursor)  IS    
CURSOR ecursor IS select emp_id 
                  from temp_employee te 
                       join payroll_info pi 
                       on te.emp_id = pi.emp_id 
                       join benefit_info bi 
                       on te.emp_id = bi.emp_id 
                  where some_column = 'some condition';
v_results NT_EMP_PAYROLL_BENEFIT;
BEGIN
   open ecursor;
   fetch ecursor bulk collect into v_results;
   close ecursor;
   for i = v_results.first..v_results.last loop
      v_results.some_benefit_column := some_payroll_column + i;
   end loop;
   open p_output for select * from table(v_results);
end;
```

Answer (score -1):

There are too many syntactical and ideological errors in your code. 
Therefore, read, please, [PL/SQL documentation here](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/toc.htm), especially [PL/SQL Architecture section](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/01_oview.htm#962) to understand difference between SQL and PL/SQL (generally SQL - query language, PL/SQL - programming language) and sections for your case:

1. ["Understanding PL/SQL Procedures"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#591) and ["Understanding PL/SQL Functions"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#657)
2. ["Cursor FOR Loops"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/01_oview.htm#767) and ["Using cursor FOR Loops"](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/06_ora.htm#1449)

Full PL/SQL reference for Oracle 9i R2 available at [this link](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/toc.htm).

Set of all Oracle 9i R2 documentation can be found [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db92/db92.docindex?remark=homepage).