# PL/SQL : loops, fetching records

Tags: plsql

I am trying to display the first name, salary and job-id of first 5 records from a table "employees" using a simple loop. However, in the output only 1st record is getting displayed. Kindly suggest where I am going wrong in the code I have written and what I should do to rectify it. Given below is the code. [Also, I have attached the screenshot of the result.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndlR8.png)

```
declare
v_i number(2) ;
v_fname employees.first_name%type;
v_sal employees.salary%type;
v_job employees.job_id%type;

begin 
      v_i:=1;
      loop
      select first_name, salary, job_id into v_fname, v_sal, v_job from 
      employees where rownum=v_i;
      dbms_output.put_line('Record ' || v_i || ': ');
      dbms_output.put_line('First Name: ' || v_fname);
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Salary: ' || v_sal);
      dbms_output.put_line( 'Job Title: ' || v_job);
      dbms_output.put_line( chr(10));
      v_i := v_i +1;
      exit when v_i >= 5;
      end loop;
end;
```

Comment: I think it says it does not have a rownum =2... no data found....

Comment: yes. but, there are 117 records in the table. I wonder what is possibly going wrong there.

Comment: the problem is the plsql keyword rownum. A thing you could do is get all 5 items first

Comment: what i mean is dont use rownum here. try using a TOP 5 select or something like that and then using a FETCH like cursor

Comment: The cursor is working fine. Thanks. :)

But, can't we achieve this using simple loop/ while loop / for loop statements?

Comment: but fetch cursors are as simple as loops... are you sure you want to use rownum to select? you dont control what row will be retrieved

Comment: Okay. This is a new learning. I thought that the order of insertion will determine the rownum value. Of course, it depends on what we are trying to retrieve.

Actually we have been given assignments. One question is to display first name, job type, and salary of first 5 records from the "employees" table using 

a) Simple for loop with “EXIT WHEN” condition
b) The “WHILE” condition
c) Cursor FOR LOOP 

Of which I could not get output for the first two. So what would you suggest for that?

Comment: order can be affected by other things like indexes

Comment: ok, after investigating... using a loop to iterate all rows in query is a very bad idea, specially since there is a functionality (FETCH) specially built for it. I am not sure if the assignment is thorougly planned...  second problem, selecting using rownum... another bad idea. it does NOT work that way.. .at all. I suggest you check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3451499/using-for-loop-to-retrieve-multiple-rows-in-oracle-procedure and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4509167/select-nth-row-from-a-table-in-oracle (see answer from sjngm)

Comment: Your suggestions have been quite helpful.Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You can't use `ROWNUM` the way you do. It only works for the first select where `v_i=1`; Try it: a select with `ROWNUM=2` will return nothing!

Here is how to do it with implicit cursor:

```
declare
  v_i number(2) ;

begin 
      v_i:=1;
    for x in (
      select first_name, salary, job_id into v_fname, v_sal, v_job from 
      employees where rownum <=5 ) loop
          dbms_output.put_line('Record ' || v_i || ': ');
          dbms_output.put_line('First Name: ' || x.first_name);
          dbms_output.put_line( 'Salary: ' || x.salary);
          dbms_output.put_line( 'Job Title: ' || x.job_id);
          dbms_output.put_line( chr(10));
          v_i := v_i +1;
      end loop;
end;
```